# Managing the metadata of Document Sets using C# and CSOM

Tags: development, document-library, csom, document-set

How to manage the metadata of document sets using C#+CSOM. Any sample code is appreciated.
 below is the code i tried for creating the `document set`.

```
       ....
         .....
     ContentType targetDocumentSetContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();
     ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new 
     ListItemCreationInformation();
    newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = 
       FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
     newItemInfo.LeafName = "Document Set1";
  //newItemInfo.FolderUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
   ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);
     newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = 
       targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();
        newListItem.Update();
        list.Update();
       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

the above code for creation of document set, but i am stuck at how to modify the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The following C# with CSOM code for your reference.

```
var siteUrl = "http://sp2013";
var username = "username";
var password = "password";
var domain = "domain";
string documentLibraryName = "DocumentLibrary";
string documentSetName = "DdocumentSet1";
string propertyName = "field1";
string updatePropertyValue = "LZ";

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
    Web site = ctx.Web;
    List docLib = site.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
    ctx.Load(docLib);
    CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
    caml.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='text'>"+documentSetName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"; ;
    ListItemCollection items = docLib.GetItems(caml);             
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    if (items.Count != 0)
    {
        ListItem item = items[0];
        var properties = item.Folder.Properties;
        properties[propertyName] = updatePropertyValue;
        item.Folder.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```